# How to get all custom post types in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I am trying to make a shortcode for Visual Composer. I have to get all the custom post types as dropdown. I am using the `get_post_types()` function, but it returns an empty array.

Here is my code:

```
 /*Post type shortcode*/
 add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'post_type_shortcode');
function post_type_shortcode(){
$args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names'; //'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
vc_map( array(
    "name" => __( "Display Post Type", "saue" ),
    "description" => "Display post type",
    "base" => "display_post_type",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => __( "Saue Theme", "saue"),
    "params" => array(
        array(
            "type"          => "dropdown",
                    //"holder"        => "div",
            "heading"       => __( "Post Type", "saue" ),
            "admin_label" => true,
            "param_name"    => "post_type",
            "value"         => $custom_post_types,
            ),
        )
    ) );
```

}

I have also tried to get it in the functions.php but result is same.

I also used `add_action('init',"function_name');`, it works within the hook but not outside of the hook.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: It works with when executing on the `init` action?

Comment: It works fine. `add_action('init','getPostTypes');
function getPostTypes()
{
  $post_types = get_post_types();
  var_export($post_types);
}` but if use `return $post_types` it returns only default post types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `admin_init` hook, which runs after init:

```
/*Post type shortcode*/
add_action( 'admin_init', 'post_type_shortcode');
function post_type_shortcode(){
$args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names'; //'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
vc_map( array(
    "name" => __( "Display Post Type", "saue" ),
    "description" => "Display post type",
    "base" => "display_post_type",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => __( "Saue Theme", "saue"),
    "params" => array(
        array(
            "type"          => "dropdown",
                    //"holder"        => "div",
            "heading"       => __( "Post Type", "saue" ),
            "admin_label" => true,
            "param_name"    => "post_type",
            "value"         => $custom_post_types,
            ),
        )
    ) );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code around the line where you are calling $custom_post_types for your shortcode values.

```
/*Post type shortcode*/
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'post_type_shortcode');
function post_type_shortcode(){
$args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names'; //'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
vc_map( array(
    "name" => __( "Display Post Type", "saue" ),
    "description" => "Display post type",
    "base" => "display_post_type",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => __( "Saue Theme", "saue"),
    "params" => array(
        array(
            "type"          => "dropdown",
            //"holder"      => "div",
            "heading"       => __( "Post Type", "saue" ),
            "admin_label"   => true,
            "param_name"    => "post_type",
            "value"         => $custom_post_types->name,//see this line
            ),
        )
    ) );
}
```

This line should return the names of the post types registered. Hope this works for you!

Comment: it fires a notice `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\...\functions.php ` and the `get_post_types` function returns nothing in this hook. :(